# How to change the language on mailchimp signup module input fields?

Tags: joomla-3.6, emails, multilingual

I have a multilingual **Joomla 3.6** Site, with English and German using **MailChimp** and the **MailChimp Signup Module**.

The issue that I have is that while I can manually translate the title and texts via the *module UI*, changing the text for the form fields seem to be more complicated. There should be translations for all of the fields, but they don't seem to get applied.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is partially complicated because the input fields themselves are pulled in from your [MailChimp profile at MailChimp.com](http://www.joomlamailer.com/support/default-topic/147-changing-the-text-in-the-subscribe-button), and are pulled into the module via the API. Also, the module references multiple language .ini files, but doesn't seem to download any of them automatically, so you may need to make your own copies of the mod_mailchimpsignup.ini for the language you want to display.